# Creating multiple short-lived objects

Tags: c#, .net, performance

Which way of writing an array of zeros to the stream is more preferable (by overall performance) if the variable @count is less than 10? I'm worried about the excessive load on the allocator and the garbage collector in the first method. On the other hand, the creation of short-lived objects in .net should be heavily optimized.

```
void Main()
{
    using(var ms = new MemoryStream()){
        Method1(ms, 5);
        Method2(ms, 5);
    }
}

void Method1(MemoryStream ms, int count){
    ms.Write(new byte[count], 0, count);
}

static byte[] PreallocatedBuffer = new byte[1024];
void Method2(MemoryStream ms, int count){
    ms.Write(PreallocatedBuffer, 0, count);
}
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/, http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2015/12/20/json-net-8-0-release-1-allocations-and-bug-fixes, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086484/in-a-loop-should-i-reuse-a-single-class-instance-or-create-new-ones

Comment: I got rid of all the bottlenecks, but the program has a lot of permanent memory allocations and i can not say exactly where the problem is. I do not know the art of profiling, doing synthetic tests is meaningless. Therefore, i'm interested in knowing the general state of things in dotnet with a massive allocation of memory.
And thanks for the links, it will be useful for me.

Comment: _"and i can not say exactly where the problem is"_ Haven't seen any problem yet.

Comment: Without speculating about the performance, the following will also work: `ms.Position = 4;ms.WriteByte(0);` I'm not sure in how far it's supported functionality though. (Position can also be used with `+=` if not starting from 0. e.g. `ms.Position += count - 1;` )

Comment: @me-name, good point, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are some cases where you can call a garbage collection. These are well described by this article

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ricom/2004/11/29/when-to-call-gc-collect/

If you have a lot of objects that become suddenly (and not periodically) useless (example : you close a big file) it seems that calling the garbage collection manually is not a bad idea